# Type of HashMap value object in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

When i **'getValue()'** the object, which is of **SomeType**, from the hash, 
i am having to cast it to SomeType. JVM is&isn't seeing it as of type **SomeType**:

JVM says **true** to the check whether that objects is **instance SomeType**. 
the method **getClass()** on that object is returning **SomeType** as well.

But, when i try to assign that object to a variable **x** declared as

```
SomeType x;
```

i get the error saying

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to A.SomeType.
```

I'm getting around it by casting the object to **SomeType** and it's OK.

But, is this routine-- why am i having to cast an object-- one that's come to life as **SomeType** 
at the first place, back to **SomeType** after it spent some time in a **HashMap**?

//================

ADD: the code.

this one below gives the error. the line w/comment "THIS LINE WORKS" is the one casting and works.

```
class SomeType {
    private int value;
    public void setValue (int value) { this.value = value; }
    public int getValue () { return this.value; }
}

 void doThis(int[] input)  {

        LinkedHashMap<Integer, SomeType> anElt = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Integer key:input)  {
    SomeType h = new SomeType();

    if (anElt.containsKey(key))  {
        h = anElt.get(key);         
        // trimmed off the rest -- nothing relevant here
    } else {
        h.setValue(key);  // ...
    }
    anElt.put(key, h);
}


 Set set = anElt.entrySet();
Set<SomeType> outSet = new LinkedHashSet<SomeType> ();

  // Get an iterator
  Iterator i = set.iterator();

  while(i.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
     System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
//   SomeType h = (SomeType)(me.getValue()); // THIS LINE WORKS. -- not the one after. 
     SomeType h = me.getValue(); 
     System.out.println(h.getValue());
}
```

Comment: How is your `HashMap` declared?

Comment: can you show the actual code?  Maps don't have getValue() method.

Comment: @Taylor - done. interesting-- took getValue() for granted, didnt notice. that part from a sample-- no tmy original.

Answer (score 1):

Java generics allows you to define a collection with the actual type of objects it will be storing. In older version of Java(i belive prior Java5), all collections used to store the raw type objects and hence every time casting was required to the actual object. But using generics you can define your collection with actual types and compiler will not let you put any other type in it. So you can define a HashMap of keys of type String and values of type Integer like this:

```
Map<String,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

further improvement in Java 7 to this concept, now you need not to define the types twice in the declaration, so this is much cleaner way in Java 7 to define the same  Map:

```
Map<String,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Using generics now you don't have to cast the values to Integer, so this will work:

```
Integer value = myMap.get("myKey");
```

you don't have to do this:

```
Integer value = (Integer)myMap.get("myKey");
```

Comment: n how does this answer my Q.

Comment: Shouldn't generally declare a variable as HashMap, use Map instead.

Comment: @user2985116 because if you declared your map with generics you probably wouldn't have this problem.]

Comment: @user2985116 check the updated answer, i believe it has all the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your `HashMap` without bounded key/value types, you're going to get a raw `Object` when you query it. This would require you to do an explicit cast to your type (not good)

If you want to take advantage of the polymorphic aspect, you need to bind your types to the declaration:

```
Map<TypeA, TypeB> map = new HashMap<TypeA, TypeB>();
```

So your problem is this:

```
Iterator i = set.iterator();
```

You need to bind `SomeType` to your iterator!!!

```
Iterator<SomeType> i = set.iterator();
```

Comment: well - let me look into this & the "bounded type" and get back if not. this isnt expaining much.

Comment: Uh please do. Generics have been a critical component of java for a long time, and you're bound to see them everywhere.

Comment: mmy hashmap is declared specifically with <TypeA, SomeType> n the objects to go in are instances of SomeType. i'm not even using a superclass pointer to anyone of them.

Comment: @user2985116 updated answer. your iterator is not declared correctly.

Comment: `Set set = anElt.entrySet();` No generics there either. `Set<SomeType> set = anElt.entrySet();`

Comment: Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Map.Entry<Integer,A.SomeType>> to Set<A.SomeType>.
must be the getKey() getValue() stuff whichever the class theyre from. looking into that.

Comment: @KepaniHaole Map.Entry has both key and value.

Comment: @user2985116 suggest you read through this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html